# HTML/CSS Responsive text

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my first responsive website. I've read about it and have a decent understanding on it. One of the problems I ran into is with text or h1-6 headers. For example, I have a button that I want to resize as I resize my browser. The button is under a class. Also in that css file I have a @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) { ... Inside the bracket I called the same class and for the width I put max-width: 50%. This works perfect. The problem I'm having is if I use element again it replaces it for the whole page even if I'm viewing it at full screen.

What I'm trying to say is for example I have a class called "keep-button" inside the css I have it as font-size:25px. Now when I go to the @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) { and change the font-size to 15px. Instead of changing the font size to 15px only at 320px screen it does it for the whole page. I've tried using font-size-adjust, but that didnt work.

Here is sample code from it:

```
 .keep-button {
    height: 70px;
    width: 430px;
    background-color: #C60;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 115px;  
}

h5 {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}


@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

.keep-button {
    max-width: 50%; 

}

h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size-adjust: .50;  
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need change `@media only screen and (min-width : 320px)` to 
`@media only screen and (max-width : 320px)`. Now when page will be less than 320px your rules will be applied. Also, try understand [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) article about media queries.

Comment: Thank you so much for that link! Yea the max-width made sense can't believe I missed that part. However it still didn't fix it. Now it seems like anything I do in the @media section gets ignored for example if for the h5 I want to font color to turn red at that screen size when I put color: red; it doesn't work neither does changing the font size. Even the max-width inside the keep button doesn't change it to 50% anymore when i changed it from min to max

Comment: Here is something I did that solved the problem in case anyone was interested instead of having **@media only screen and (max-width : 320px)** I changed it to **@media all and (max-width: 599px) and (min-width: 320px)**

Comment: @Hashtag look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hLqo1bpu/s). Everything working fine!